# PIG date conversion issue sample date is 4/1/2009 9:06:00 AM

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
bill_details= FOREACH bill_details_raw GENERATE 
              $0 AS invD_icode, $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
              $2 AS invD_InvH_No,
              ToDate(invD_InvH_date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS dateString,  
              $5 AS invD_pro_icode,
              $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
              $7 AS invD_pro_name,  
              $8 AS invD_qty;



java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-85 Operator Key: scope-85) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: " invD_InvH_date"
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:549)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name: POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS)[datetime] - scope-85 Operator Key: scope-85) children: null at []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: " invD_InvH_date"
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:338)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.runPipeline(PigGenericMapBase.java:282)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:277)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapBase.map(PigGenericMapBase.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: " invD_InvH_date"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:899)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS.exec(ToDate2ARGS.java:45)
    at org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate2ARGS.exec(ToDate2ARGS.java:33)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextDateTime(POUserFunc.java:422)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:329)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Hint, your logs say `Invalid format: " invD_InvH_date"` ...

Comment: By the way, Pig doesn't remove headers from files

Comment: Have you tried with one 'a' for AM/PM ? ToDate(invD_InvH_date,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a') AS dateString,

Comment: yes i have tried but same result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bill_details= FOREACH bill_details_raw GENERATE $0 AS invD_icode,
             $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
             $2 AS invD_InvH_No, 
            ToDate($3,' M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS dateString,
            $5 AS invD_pro_icode, 
            $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
            $7 AS invD_pro_name, 
            $8 AS invD_qty;
```

Comment: how is it different from my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to convert the given string to date without any issue. 
Here is the code that works.

**date.txt**

```
4/1/2009 9:06:00 AM
```

**Code**

```
file_date = load 'date.txt';
dates_only = foreach file_data generate ToDate($0, 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa');
```

**output**

```
dump file_date;
(4/1/2009 9:06:00 AM)
dump dates_only
(2009-04-01T09:06:00.000Z)
```

**Possible Solution:**

I think the issue is, you are using column name, now I am not sure weather it's part of schema or not, it doesn't seems though.

Can you try this?

```
bill_details= FOREACH bill_details_raw GENERATE 
              $0 AS invD_icode, 
              $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
              $2 AS invD_InvH_No,
              ToDate($3,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS dateString,  
              $5 AS invD_pro_icode,
              $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
              $7 AS invD_pro_name,  
              $8 AS invD_qty;
```

Comment: bill_details= FOREACH bill_details_raw GENERATE 
              $0 AS invD_icode, 
              $1 AS invD_InvH_icode, 
              $2 AS invD_InvH_No,
              ToDate($3,' M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa') AS dateString,  
              $5 AS invD_pro_icode,
              $6 AS invD_pro_ucode, 
              $7 AS invD_pro_name,  
              $8 AS invD_qty;

Comment: @PranavChaturvedi i don't understand your comment?

Comment: difference is in To_date function where in  data format string  i have mentioned space before M